# Bypass ssl through iis

Tags: iis, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

good day.
i'm continue experiments with k8s, i'm resetting it, again, and do all from white page:
- install single node k8s,
- install nginx ingress controller
- install cert-manager
- create issuer and make certificate, and viola - it's work. i can obtain certificate from let's encrypt

but now i have some trouble which come from network infrastructure.
we have public IP and dns record for it, this is a gateway which forward request from 80 and 443 port to private server
private server with win 2016 and iis with url_rewrite module

i have rule for rewrite incoming request to k8s machine and certificate request finish successful, i can access my service from WAN via http, but if i try to access via https i got 502 error and this is not surprised, because i need to setup https binding for site, but i need ssl certificate for it.. certificate that obtained by cert-manager and stored in k8s cluster...

so, my question - is is possible to implement such scheme: https -> gateway -> iis -> k8s with let's encrypt certificates and if it is possible how i should setup https binding?

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming. ServerFault is the place to go.

Comment: How about use SSL offloading for your reverse proxy instead? It is hard to bypass schannel unless you setup a CA cert https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/